# Getting E/Camera: Error 2 and E/Camera: Error 1 when trying to take a picture with custom camera App

Tags: android, android-studio, camera, android-camera

I am currently building a custom camera app to sample and classify pictures of climbing knots.
At first I had some troubles adding the pictures to my gallery, but I was able to fix it on my personal device (OP3) by using the gallersyAddPic() method as described in a different SO post.
Now that I have tried to use the app on different devices (Pixel 3, 4XL), I had to notice that this solution only worked for my device.

```
public class SampleActivity extends Activity {
    private static String knotName = "unknown";
    private Camera mCamera;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sample);

        Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openMainActivity();
            }
        });

        mCamera = getCameraInstance();
        CameraPreview mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
        FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
        preview.addView(mPreview);

        Button captureButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_capture);
        captureButton.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // get an image from the camera
                        mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
                        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Picture taken", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
        );

    }

    private final Camera.PictureCallback mPicture = new Camera.PictureCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

            File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
            if (pictureFile == null){
                Log.d(TAG, "Error creating media file, check storage permissions");
                return;
            }

            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                fos.write(data);
                fos.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    };

    public void openMainActivity() {
        releaseCamera();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    /** A safe way to get an instance of the Camera object. */
    public static Camera getCameraInstance(){
        Camera c = null;
        try {
            c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
        }
        return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
    }

    private void releaseCamera(){
        if (mCamera != null){
            mCamera.release();        // release the camera for other applications
            mCamera = null;
        }
    }

    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = 2;

    /** Create a file Uri for saving an image or video */
    private Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type){
        return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
    }

    /** Create a File for saving an image or video */
    private File getOutputMediaFile(int type){
        // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
        // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.

        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "KnotSampler");
        // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
        // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.

        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
            if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
                Log.d("KnotSampler", "failed to create directory");
                return null;
            }
        }

        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE){
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                    knotName + timeStamp + ".jpg");
        } else if(type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                    "VID_"+ timeStamp + ".mp4");
        } else {
            return null;
        }
        galleryAddPic();
        return mediaFile;
    }


    private void galleryAddPic() {
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        Uri contentUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(1);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
        this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
    }

    public static void setKnotName(String name){
        knotName = name;
    }
}
```

Since the error logs are also not really helping me, I would be glad if someone of you could help me out.

```
2020-11-08 13:45:14.273 23133-23133/com.example.knotsampler2 I/Oscillator: Available resolution: 640 480
2020-11-08 13:45:14.273 23133-23133/com.example.knotsampler2 I/Oscillator: Available resolution: 352 288
2020-11-08 13:45:14.273 23133-23133/com.example.knotsampler2 I/Oscillator: Available resolution: 320 240
2020-11-08 13:45:14.273 23133-23133/com.example.knotsampler2 I/Oscillator: Available resolution: 176 144
2020-11-08 13:45:14.274 23133-23133/com.example.knotsampler2 I/Oscillator: Available resolution: 1280 720
2020-11-08 13:45:14.274 23133-23133/com.example.knotsampler2 I/Oscillator: Available resolution: 1280 960
2020-11-08 13:45:14.277 23133-23133/com.example.knotsampler2 I/Oscillator: Chosen resolution: 1280 720
2020-11-08 13:45:15.051 23133-23163/com.example.knotsampler2 I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=1073ms; Flags=1, IntendedVsync=13393706587741, Vsync=13393923254399, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=13393939136800, AnimationStart=13393939180000, PerformTraversalsStart=13393939882800, DrawStart=13394689472200, SyncQueued=13394695413100, SyncStart=13394700149800, IssueDrawCommandsStart=13394701941300, SwapBuffers=13394713497300, FrameCompleted=13394784538900, DequeueBufferDuration=38178300, QueueBufferDuration=1433400, GpuCompleted=0, 
2020-11-08 13:45:15.084 23133-23163/com.example.knotsampler2 I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=1095ms; Flags=1, IntendedVsync=13393706587741, Vsync=13393923254399, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=13393939136800, AnimationStart=13393939180000, PerformTraversalsStart=13393939882800, DrawStart=13394787304600, SyncQueued=13394787496500, SyncStart=13394792589400, IssueDrawCommandsStart=13394792728600, SwapBuffers=13394799823700, FrameCompleted=13394807610300, DequeueBufferDuration=3065200, QueueBufferDuration=1804200, GpuCompleted=0, 
2020-11-08 13:45:15.090 23133-23133/com.example.knotsampler2 I/Choreographer: Skipped 53 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2020-11-08 13:45:15.164 23133-23163/com.example.knotsampler2 I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=954ms; Flags=0, IntendedVsync=13393939881802, Vsync=13394823215100, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=13394823672000, AnimationStart=13394823805400, PerformTraversalsStart=13394824852500, DrawStart=13394833646800, SyncQueued=13394833704300, SyncStart=13394836524900, IssueDrawCommandsStart=13394836656600, SwapBuffers=13394839535700, FrameCompleted=13394896844000, DequeueBufferDuration=31648300, QueueBufferDuration=1166200, GpuCompleted=0, 
2020-11-08 13:45:15.182 23133-23163/com.example.knotsampler2 I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=908ms; Flags=0, IntendedVsync=13393939881802, Vsync=13394823215100, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=13394823672000, AnimationStart=13394823805400, PerformTraversalsStart=13394824852500, DrawStart=13394837034800, SyncQueued=13394837499500, SyncStart=13394904498100, IssueDrawCommandsStart=13394904555000, SwapBuffers=13394912547600, FrameCompleted=13394915122200, DequeueBufferDuration=901700, QueueBufferDuration=901600, GpuCompleted=0, 
2020-11-08 13:45:17.356 23133-23133/com.example.knotsampler2 E/Camera: Error 2
2020-11-08 13:45:25.369 23133-23133/com.example.knotsampler2 E/Camera: Error 1
```

Thanks in advance,
snoopeyy

Comment: I'm also getting the Error 2 and Error 1 messages, did you find a solution?

Comment: Same issue here suddenly on my device. Any solution for that?